# Vectors and shapes

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

In a regular hexagon, $\vec{AB}$+$\vec{AC}$+$\vec{AD}$+$\vec{AE}$+$\vec{AF}$=**k**$\vec{AD}$, then what is the value of **k**?

Concepts I know, 
Triangle and parallelogram law of vector addition.

Comment: Hint: use coordinates.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: Okay I'll let you know how far I reach

Comment: I have drawn one, yes no doubt about it. I also know that every interior angle will be equal to $120^{°}$ if that's of any use.

Comment: Use the symmetry and group them as $(\vec{AB} + \vec{AF})+(\vec{AC} + \vec{AE}) + \vec{AD}$.

Comment: @dxiv I get it, so how to find the resultant of those pairs because I need to get them to convert to $\vec{AD}$

Comment: For example $\vec{AB} + \vec{AF}$ gives a vector collinear with $\vec{AD}$ of modulus $|AB|$.

Comment: $(\vec{AB} + \vec{AF}) = (\vec{AO})$ where $O$ is the center of the hexagon.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$ (\vec{AB}+\vec{AE})+\vec{AD}+(\vec{AF}+\vec{AC}) $$
and remember that $\vec{AB}=\vec{ED}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{AB}=a$ and $\vec{AF}=b$.  Then $\vec{AC}=b+2a$, $\vec{AD}=2a+2a$, $\vec{AE}=2b+a$.  Hence 
$$\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}+\vec{AD}+\vec{AE}+\vec{AF}=6b+6a=3\vec{AD}.$$

Comment: the answer is right but could you explain it a little bit clearer and use a diagram maybe